# Excel formula for complex 2d table sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out the the formulas that would go in B13:B16 that would yield a total for each User in A:3:A10) for all 2024Qx columns from Actual amount if it's not not-zero or from Budget amount otherwise.
So for example B13 should be a total of all quarters (so 2024Q1+2024Q2+2024Q3+2024Q4) and for rows 3:10 where user in A3:A10 match user in $A$13 and taking either actual amounts if not 0, (so (if Cx <> 0 then Cx else Bx) + (if Ex <> 0 then Ex else Dx)+(if Gx <> 0 then Gx else Fx)+(if Ix <> 0 then Ix else Hx)+.. for as many actual columns as exist (example shows only one year, but I'd need something scalable for multiple years, so the formula should rely on the headers containing either "Actual" or "Budget" strings), and for x in (3:10). The same idea for all B13:B16.
The example below provides the totals that the formulas should amount to as a verification check.
I'm not sure if this is doable using something like SUMPRODUCTS, or am I firmly within VBA macro teritory.

| USERS | 2024Q1 |  | 2024Q2 |  | 2024Q3 |  | 2024Q4 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Budget | Actual | Budget | Actual | Budget | Actual | Budget | Actual |
| A | $8,900.00 | $2,700.00 | $2,800.00 | $2,800.00 | $8,500.00 | $3,900.00 | $2,500.00 |  |
| A | $7,400.00 | $9,500.00 | $4,400.00 | $800.00 | $2,100.00 | $1,800.00 | $7,900.00 | $900.00 |
| B | $2,900.00 | $7,200.00 | $4,500.00 |  | $2,500.00 |  | $1,500.00 |  |
| C | $7,200.00 | $7,100.00 | $2,900.00 | $300.00 | $7,100.00 | $800.00 | $6,100.00 |  |
| B | $7,200.00 |  | $9,600.00 | $3,300.00 | $6,700.00 | $7,200.00 | $3,100.00 | $8,700.00 |
| D | $7,500.00 | $8,300.00 | $4,700.00 |  | $4,700.00 |  | $4,600.00 | $5,200.00 |
| A | $8,300.00 | $7,900.00 | $9,100.00 | $6,700.00 | $9,300.00 |  | $8,700.00 |  |
| D | $4,600.00 | $7,000.00 | $8,200.00 | $6,700.00 | $4,300.00 |  | $2,000.00 |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| USERS | Total |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A | $57,500.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| B | $42,100.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| C | $14,300.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D | $42,900.00 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:D4)*(E1:E4))`. So (A1:D4) represents the range of values in the 2D table, and (E1:E4) represents the corresponding weights or factors.

Comment: I modified the example a bit, to align with the example. I'm not sure if it clarifies the question a bit. So the data to sum up is in B3:I10, the Users to match are in A3:10.

Comment: What you want to do is called "unpivot a table". 

You can use PowerQuery for that. 

Here is a good tutorial from MS. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/12/15/learn-how-to-unpivot-static-tables-in-excel-2016/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a version compatible to older Excel versions, this may be an option:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR($C$3:$I$10*($C$2:$I$2="Actual")/($C$3:$I$10<>""),$B$3:$H$10)*($A$3:$A$10=A13))`

This starts from column C (first `Actual`-column) up to the last column containing data and checks the columns to have a header equal to `Actual` and sums the cells contains a value. If they don't, this enforces an error (#DIV/0!); in that case IFERROR adds the value of the cell left from the error location.

Comment: Hey, P.b, I run into an issue in this formula though. If one of the quarter has neither budget not actual amount, and a previous quarter has an actual amount that's non zero, then that actual amount shall be included twice. Seems that On Error adds the value that's 2 columns to the left it doesn't find anything in the column directly to the left..

Comment: For example if for user C (data line 4) we remove the 6100, which is the 2024Q4 Budget, then the previous Actual amount (800) would be added twice.

Comment: That is correct, the question was if the actual would be empty use the budget. And budget was all filled in your example. So my formula only allows `actual` values to be empty. If you have possible empty budget values the question changes from what it currently is: `=SUM(IFERROR($C$3:$I$10*($C$2:$I$2="Actual")/($C$3:$I$10<>""),$B$3:$H$10)*($A$3:$A$10=A13)*($B$2:$H$2="Budget"))`

Answer (score 0):

*If I have understood correctly, and not mistaking anything here, then the following formula should work as is, the only assumption here as per the tags posted there is no `Excel Constraints`. Therefore, the following formula posted **Exclusively** works with **MS365** Users only. Note that the formula is dynamic and will certainly work for any number of columns, so one dont need to extend the range every time there is a new data added.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B13</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _LastCol, AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),1)+1,
     _Data, TAKE(1:10,,_LastCol),
     _Users, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),2),
     _DataBody, TAKE(_Data,,-_LastCol+1),
     _FillUps, SCAN(0,IF((_DataBody=0)*(INDEX(_DataBody,2,)="Budget"),"a",_DataBody),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y))),
     _Actuals, DROP(CHOOSECOLS(_FillUps,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_DataBody)/2,2,2)),2),
     BYROW(A13:A16,LAMBDA(a, SUM(IFERROR(_Actuals*(a=_Users),0)))))
```

---

Also the above solution can be made bit shorter:

```
=LET(
     _LastCol, AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),1)+1,
     _Data, TAKE(1:10,,_LastCol),
     _Users, DROP(TAKE(_Data,,1),2),
     _DataBody, TAKE(_Data,,-_LastCol+1),
     _FillUps, SCAN(0,IF((_DataBody=0)*(INDEX(_DataBody,2,)="Budget"),"a",_DataBody),LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y))),
     _Actuals, DROP(FILTER(_FillUps,INDEX(_DataBody,2,)="Actual"),2),
     BYROW(A13:A16,LAMBDA(a, SUM(IFERROR(_Actuals*(a=_Users),0)))))
```

---

- Using `LET()` function helps to define variables and makes easier to read without repeating any formulas or ranges.
- `_LastCol` variable uses `AGGREGATE()` function to get the last non empty column, since it may be possible the actuals will be blank hence `+1` is added to include it.
- `_Data` variable pulls all the data in the range based on the `_LastCol` uses `INDEX()` function and cell `A1` as first reference to create a reference range.
- `_Users` variable using `DROP()` & `TAKE()` function extracts the users.
- `_DataBody` is the complete data excluding the users.
- `_FillUps` uses `SCAN()` function to pass a custom `LAMBDA()` calculation to fill up the empty/blanks.
- `_Actulas` refers to the actual values, dynamically extracts using `CHOOSECOLS()` & `SEQUENCE()` function where the latter creates a sequence of even numbers.
- Lastly, using `BYROW()` function to perform custom `LAMBDA()` calculation to get the sum of respective users into one single array.

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)` and what I see it will be **easier** & **simpler**/**flexible**/**scalable**/**efficient** to achieve using the said tool.

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps: (Read the steps annotations to follow)

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    First2Rows = Table.FirstN(Source,2),
    Rows2Columns = Table.FillDown(Table.Transpose(First2Rows),{"Column1"}),
    Merged = Table.CombineColumns(Rows2Columns,{"Column1", "Column2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    Columns2Rows = Table.Transpose(Merged),
    Combined = Table.Combine({Columns2Rows,Table.RemoveFirstN(Source,2)}),
    PromotedHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(Combined, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    AddedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(PromotedHeaders, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    ColNames = Table.ColumnNames(AddedIndex),
    ReplaceNulls = Table.ReplaceValue(AddedIndex,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,ColNames),
    UnpivotOtherCols = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(ReplaceNulls, {"USERS|", "Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    ReplaceZeros = Table.ReplaceValue(UnpivotOtherCols,0,null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"}),
    CustomConditionAdded = Table.AddColumn(ReplaceZeros, "Condition", each if Text.Contains([Attribute],"Budget") and [Value]= null then 0 else [Value]),
    FillDown = Table.FillDown(CustomConditionAdded,{"Condition"}),
    Filter = Table.SelectRows(FillDown, each Text.Contains([Attribute], "Actual")),
    RemovedCols = Table.RemoveColumns(Filter,{"Index", "Attribute","Value"}),
    Answer = Table.Group(RemovedCols, {"USERS|"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Condition]), type number}})
in
    Answer
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Excel File Can Be Downloaded From **[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck0MWV4D2u78Hvtbc?e=O4j7Xk)**.

---

If you dont want a more flexible and scalable approach then use the following:

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A13:A16,LAMBDA(a, SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(
 SCAN(0,IF((B2:I2="Budget")*(B3:I10=""),"",B3:I10),
 LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y=0,x,y))),B2:I2="Actual")*(a=A3:A10),0))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks @Mayukh, that's quite a formula. I'll review properly in a bit. For now, just plugging it in, I get #SPILL!. I see on your screenshot that you're coming to 57500 but the total you should be getting is 64500, which is reflected by formula =SUM(C3,E3,G3,H3,C4,E4,G4,H4,C9,E9,F9,H9)

Comment: @Lukasz I get $57,500.00 as well following the logic of your question.

Comment: @Lukasz H4 should be I4 in your sum

Comment: Yes, totally my bad. P b - that's what it was. Thank You. I'll edit and correct the screenshot to not confuse the future generation.  I'm still getting the #SPILL! though.

Comment: I got past the spill now trying the MS365 LET formula (the first one), but it has the same issue as the P.b's SUMPRODUCT one: if one quarter doesn't have a budget or an actual, then this will take the non-zero amount from a previous quarter and reuse it.

Comment: Hi @MayukhBhattacharya, Thank you for your solution. I retried it and looks like you added a new version that gets around the issue of reusing the actual amount from previous quarter when both budget and actual amounts are empty. Thank you again!